# How to deauthorize an iPhone without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, authorization

I no longer wish to use my old iPhone 3GS. 
I used to use my Apple-ID to log into The iTunes & App Store on it.

Since I use that Apple-ID for iTunes & App Store on several other iDevices, I want to completely deauthorize and unregister the iPhone 3GS from my Apple-ID.

I have already signed out of iTunes & App Store on it. Can and should I "deauthorize" it in any other way?

I no longer use the iTunes program on any computer, so the iPhone is not connected or synced to any computer of mine . (And I don't want to install iTunes, I don't like the program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly deauthorize it. The standard way is to use iTunes.

But if you do not want to install or use iTunes, you can get Apple Support to help you:

- Go to the [Apple iTunes Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/) page
- Click on the **Contact iTunes Store support** link (click OK when it prompts you about redirecting you to another page)
- This currently takes you to the **What's happening with iTunes?** page
- Click the **Account Management** box to open up further options
- Click the **iTunes authorization or de-authorization** link
- Choose how you would like help - the current options are for Apple to call you or to schedule a call back from Apple or email Apple Support
- Provide the details of the Apple ID and the device in the request for deauthorization

Comment: Thats very interesting. I'm guessing if you buy an iOS device and don't want to use iTunes (albeit making life more difficult for yourself), you could authorise the device in this way as well ?

Comment: Authorization is the process for the iTunes/App Stores that allows you to play or use content you purchase from these stores on the device or computer. When you sign in to the iTunes or App stores on a device, it gets authorized automatically (with the associated Apple ID).

Comment: @MK The authorization limit only applies to Macs. You don't need to unauthorize an iOS device.

Comment: Both Macs and iOS devices are counted for the authorization limit. See http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/more-than-five-family-devices-sharing-a-single-itunes-account/

Answer (score 1):

According to apple support, it can only be done via iTunes. There is no need to sync it with iTunes on a pc to deauthorize it. Just sign in to iTunes, go to account page and deauthorize it.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1420

Comment: When you say "sign in to iTunes" do you mean online, using a web browser? In that case, what URL? I have tried logging in to https://appleid.apple.com/‎ and no devices at all are shown there.

Comment: No, I mean on a pc or a mac with iTunes program installed, log in and follow the procedure from Apple's support page.

Comment: Ok, then I wasn't clear: I do not have iTunes installed and I do not wish to install it. I want to remove an iDevice without any locally installed program.

Comment: I wasn't clear too: There is no other way to do it other than installing iTunes or use someone else's pc with itunes installed.

Comment: @NikosM. So you can go to any PC/Mac with iTunes installed in order to carry out the deauthorisation ?

Comment: Yes, just log in with your itunes credentials.

Comment: @NikosM. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to Never Use iTunes With Your iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch](http://www.howtogeek.com/175045/how-to-never-use-itunes-with-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch/) there was a time when Apple device users had to plug their devices into their PCs or Macs and use iTunes for device activation, updates, and syncing, but iTunes is no longer necessary.

Apple still allows you to use iTunes for these things, but you don’t have to. Your iOS device can function independently from iTunes, so you should never be forced to plug it into a PC or Mac.

The Article will explain:

- Device Activation
- Operating System Updates
- Purchased iTunes Media
- Music
- Podcasts
- Backups
- Personal Data
- Photos

Hopefully it will be of help to you and others who may not wish to use iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to/can't unauthorized iOS devices since you can use as many iOS devices with the same Apple ID as you like. You only need to unauthorize Macs because only a max of 5 can be authorized with your Apple ID. If you are getting rid of your 3GS I suggest you simply do a whole device reset.