# Apple ID password compromised - 2FA rescued - What next?

Tags: security, apple-id, hacking

I have a Mac, iPhone and an iPad. I use my Gmail account for the Apple ID and one day, I received a notification on my phone that someone is trying to login with my gmail account. The two factor authentication message popped up and I chose *Do not allow*. So, it didn’t even come up with the 6 digit code (2FA is fantastic!).

I then later changed my Apple ID password to something long, complicated and to something which I don’t use anywhere else (nor used in the past).

The whole thing happened because I had reused a password (bad, I know and it is my mistake).

Now, when I login to the appleid page, I see only these three devices (MacBook, iPad and iPhone) and nothing else.

- Does this mean that my account is now safe?
- Is there an activity page to see where my Apple ID is being used?
- Should I now go about resetting the passwords which are part of the keychain?

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask for account data on https://privacy.apple.com and see if there is any active login. I don't remember if successful are counted only, or all.

Uncheck all irrelevant boxes and you'll soon get the email about data availability.

> - Your Apple ID account details and sign-in records.
> - Records of your Apple retail store and support transactions.

etc can be accessed. [Source](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208502)

Related write-ups

- [Does apple automatically sign out all connected devices when you change the apple id password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143405/does-apple-automatically-sign-out-all-connected-devices-when-you-change-the-appl?rq=1)
- [Does someone know my (old) Apple ID password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239335/does-someone-know-my-old-apple-id-password?rq=1)
- [If you think your Apple ID has been compromised](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204145) Apple Support. however, this doesn't address the intermediate case of failed login.
- [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204915) This mentions one more point of trusted phone numbers. Verification code could have been sent to a phone number too. So check your trusted phone numbers. They can be checked in  Settings > [your name] > Password & Security.

*Personal notes:*

A failed 2FA is an indicator of failed login, thus as far as I can think, no other device has the login. Only trusted devices can log-in directly without 2FA code. If either your trusted devices or trusted phone numbers are physically captured, they can be used to log-in. Keychain items are visible only on devices, not on web. For iOS, in Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Website & App Passwords.
For Mac, in Keychain access.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203783#stored

Comment: Thanks! I have asked Apple for the same. In the meantime, when I login to `Find my` and look through at it, I find only these three devices of mine. I do not see anything else. Is that an indication that no one else has signed into an Apple device using my Apple ID? Secondly, even they have simply accessed my Apple ID account, can they get access to my passwords out of the Keychain? Sorry, I use Apple devices but I am not a tech-savy person.

Comment: well a failed 2FA is an indicator of failed login, thus as far as I can think, no other device has the login. Only trusted devices can login directly without 2FA code. **2** if either your trusted devices are physically captured, they can be used to view passwords. Keychain items are visible only on devices, not on web.

Comment: See the edit too.