# Security issue logging in to the App Store using different Apple ID

Tags: itunes, icloud, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

Does your device get **logged** or **added to relevant Apple ID's account device list** when you logout from the *App Store* using, for example, your iPad device, and login back again with another ID?

Example case: your friend uses your iPad and logs in to the App Store using his ID. Will your iPad's serial no., backups, data or any other sensitive information be stored on your friend's Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mixed. While the iTunes app store can be signed into with a separate Apple ID, there will be some data (naturally) stored on the second account you use. The device will not be added to their My Apple Devices, though it will become an Authorized Device in iTunes Store. As such, some level of data will be held in the Apple Servers to facilitate this transaction. AFAIK this data is not user-accessible.

However, for data backups, Photos, Find my iPhone, My Apple Devices, etc. that would require the user to login via iCloud on the phone and not just the Apple Store. From there, whatever level of data you set to sync would be replicated up. Please note, you CAN be signed into a separate iCloud and iTunes account, as well as various other services (such as separate iCloud and Messages accounts).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to prevent a device becoming an "Authorised Device" on iTunes (remove it from the authorised devices list)?

Comment: To deauthorize an iTunes device, please refer to: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107783/how-to-deauthorize-an-iphone-without-itunes or http://www.imore.com/how-deauthorize-devices-linked-your-itunes-account

Comment: What if you do not have an access to that Apple ID (e.g. a friend's Apple ID)? Does the "Authorised Device" status give an Apple ID holder a particular privilege, i.e. allow to do something with the device, like access data?

Comment: No, it simply allows apps, songs, or anything able to be downloaded from the App store to continue to be used on the device it is authorized with. No data (I think the name of the device is all) is visible to the user who owns the ID.

Comment: Will "the status" expire/disappear from the list after some time?

Comment: No. The user AFAIK has to remove it