# Apple ID is signed into iCloud with old ID

Tags: itunes

How can I sundown old Apple ID that is signed into App Store and new ID is signed into everything else? Old IPhone was stolen along with the old ID by stalker.

Comment: Can't you just change the password on the old ID?

Comment: I did change the password on old Id but it stays the same with iTunes being signed into old ID and new iCloud signed into everything else. Stalker has hacked all Apple products I have.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107827/9058 might help. Or contact Apple Support directly.

Comment: You have a couple of options here.  You can deauthorize computers with the old ID or you can contact Apple to ask them to cancel the old ID.  Have you tried either of those?

Comment: Yes but stalker/ hacker has been doing this to me for almost four years and when I signed up for this site- I got two iCloud emails so I appreciate the input

Comment: If that's the case, I would recommend you [contact Apple directly](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232) and tell them to cancel that ID.